# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting this error when I set the background image of a UIButton

PlayeridViewController.h

```
@interface PlayeridViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *gotoboard;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *newplayerlbl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tetpid;

@end
```

Below is my view did load method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    bgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Loginbg"];
    [self.view insertSubview:bgView atIndex:0];
    _newplayerlbl.hidden=NO;
    _tetpid.hidden=NO;


    //Code that presents or dismisses a view controller here

_newplayerlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_playerid];

NSLog(@"%@",_playerid);
[_gotoboard setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"go to board"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_gotoboard setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"go to board"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (IBAction)gotoboard:(id)sender {
    //Code that presents or dismisses a view controller here

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b4" sender:self];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

it crashes in the last line and I tried `dispatch_async` under that I used from the line

`_newplayerlbl.hidden=NO;`
to

```
[_gotoboard setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"go to board"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

it was crashing this time to

What is the problem here? What is the solution?
Thanks in Advance

My exception message is

```
2017-08-17 10:31:04.528 BarrelBoard[13094:83433] *** Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/Keyboard/UIKeyboardTaskQueue.m:432
2017-08-17 10:31:04.538 BarrelBoard[13094:83433] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '- [UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010364bb0b     __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001030b0141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010364fcf2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000102c4a536 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   UIKit                               0x0000000104c95f6f -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 165
5   UIKit                               0x0000000104416515 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:] + 1372
6   UIKit                               0x000000010482c63d -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 992
7   UIKit                               0x0000000104835c4b -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _preserveInputViewsWithId:animated:reset:] + 499
8   UIKit                               0x000000010430c35d -[UIViewController _presentViewController:modalSourceViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 1145
9   UIKit                               0x000000010430dfae -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 4660
10  UIKit                               0x0000000104310e8a -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 532
11  UIKit                               0x0000000104310962 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 181
12  UIKit                               0x0000000104315c94 -[UIViewController _showViewController:withAction:sender:] + 274
13  UIKit                               0x00000001047c6fe1 __66-[UIStoryboardShowSegueTemplate newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:]_block_invoke + 134
14  UIKit                               0x0000000104920444 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 447
15  UIKit                               0x0000000104920254 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 82
16  UIKit                               0x00000001042fde47 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 99
17  BarrelBoard                         0x0000000102acedb9 __32-[MemberViewController submitb:]_block_invoke + 441
18  CFNetwork                           0x000000010601b87b __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
19  CFNetwork                           0x000000010601b095 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 143
20  Foundation                          0x0000000102bba3b7 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
21  Foundation                          0x0000000102bba0bb -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
22  Foundation                          0x0000000102bb8877 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 627
23  Foundation                          0x0000000102bb45fc __NSOQSchedule_f + 198
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106b5205c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106b3094f _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 221
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106b31669 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1084
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106b33ec4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 634
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000106b33bef _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000106ee95a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000106ee907d start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Below is my code of submitb

```
- (IBAction)submitb:(id)sender {
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
if (_phonum.text.length==10) {


    _memnums=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_memnum.text];
    _phonums=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_phonum.text];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@",_memnums,_phonums);
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"membership_number=%@ & phone_number= %@",_memnums,_phonums];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    //  Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    // Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our postData
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://riterp.com/barrel/getplayer_id.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);
    //   And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new NSURLSession:
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
        NSLog(@"Reply = %@", requestReply);
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
        NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", jsonDict);
        _playerd=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"player_id"];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b2" sender:self];

    }] resume];
   }
    else{


    _errorimg.hidden=NO;
    _phonenumanim.duration=0.5;
    _phonenumanim.type=CSAnimationTypeShake;
    _phonenumanim.delay=0.5;


    [self.view addSubview:_phonenumanim];
    [_phonenumanim startCanvasAnimation];


    UIAlertController *alertController=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Incorrect Phone Number!!" message:@"Please enter a valid Phone Number!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {

                               }];
    [alertController addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
 });

}
```

Comment: Are you trtying to set these images from a background thread/queue?

Comment: I did try dispatching in main queue too above is my current code and crashes at the last line

Comment: Where have you initialized `gotoboard` ?

Comment: Please post your entire code.

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *gotoboard;

Comment: As you say that you use dispatch_async, Please make sure all the UI updates should be done in main thread, not background thread

Comment: yes I know that I tried that and gave error @NehaGupta

Comment: Can you share us the Error Message / Exception you are in ?

Comment: have edited the question check again

Comment: any idea?? how to solve this

Comment: Defiantly issue with Concurrent task executed because of Async

Answer (score 0):

The issue from the crash log points to performing of segue from submit method of `MemberViewController` from a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform your segue from the main thread as the error message suggests. Enclose the code in the completion block of your task in `[MemberViewController submitb:]` in a GCD call, e. g.:

```
// Inside of the completion block
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Insert the code of the completion block here
    [self performSegue...];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I tried taking the segue code out of post method now it works without error the submit button action.                                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b2" sender:self]; was taken out of the post method